# jQuery: Return javascript array from Ajax-callback

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a Ajax-call made from jQuery to return a JavaScript array generated by PHP, but can't get it accessible. Here is what I am doing:

1. I run the following code onLoad:
   `$(function() {
   jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'retrieve.php',
   success: function(data) {
   },
   async: false
   }, "script");`
2. **retrieve.php** returns the following (**retrieve.php** does the formatting, and echoes it out):
   `var data = {
   "info" : [{
   "title": "Title",
   "description": "Description"
   }],
   "playlist" : [
   {
   "title": "In This Place",
   "subTitle": "Excalibur",
   "href": "http://localhost/manger/ny/#desemberkonsert_in-this-place",
   "url": "../flv/desemberkonsert/21_in_this_place.flv",
   "thumbnail": "../flv/desemberkonsert/21_in_this_place_thumbnail.png",
   "time": "5:39"
   }, {
   "title": "Black Hole",
   "subTitle": "Excalibur",
   "href": "http://localhost/manger/ny/#desemberkonsert_black-hole",
   "url": "../flv/desemberkonsert/22_black_hole.flv",
   "thumbnail": "../flv/desemberkonsert/22_black_hole_thumbnail.png",
   "time": "4:26"
   }]
   }`
3. I then try to access this code using for example: `$("#placeholder").text(data.playlist[0]["title"]);`
4. This returns as "undefined"

The array does work when I copy and paste it directly onto the file, but when returned as a callback it fails. How do I access the returned array?

Comment: Why not return this as JSON? Additionally your PHP is going to have to set the appropriate content-type header

Comment: I tried switching it to json in the ajax-call (also removed 'var data = ' from retrieve.php), which content-type would I set it to? Is there a specific one for json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return just the object, not a string of JavaScript which assigns the object to a name. That's NOT a JSON response.

Your code which uses the object should be in the success handler of the ajax call, not separate code somewhere else.

Comment: I removed the 'var data = ' part of it, and moved my `$("#placeholder").text(data.playlist[0]["title"]);` code into the callback (also told the ajax call to return "json"). It does still return "undefined" however, what is going wrong?

Comment: Time to learn to use a javascript debugger, like firebug or the developer tools built into chrome/ie.

Comment: I am using Firebug, and the "data" response from retrieve.php is valid enough, but I still cannot access it within the callback (as for example `$("#placeholder").text(data.playlist[0]["title"]);`)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to access your data with the [] notation, and not the . object notation:

```
data["playlist"][0]["title"]
```

Comment: This appears to make no difference in regards to results, both will return "undefined".